# Python. Как вытащить словарь из html?

Tags: python-3.x

Добрый день. Как из вот этой каши вытащить словарь data-params?

```
<div class="subcategory-product-item product_data__gtm-js product_data__pageevents-js ddl_product" data-gtm-position="1" data-list-id="main" data-params='{"id":"393591","categoryId":214,"price":2290,"shortName":"Смартфон ARK Benefit S402 черный","categoryName":"Мобильные телефоны","brandName":"ARK"}'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вначале можно воспользоваться регулярными выражениями для выделения нужного куска текста:

```
import re

s = '<div class="subcategory-product-item product_data__gtm-js product_data__pageevents-js ddl_product" data-gtm-position="1" data-list-id="main" data-params=\'{"id":"393591","categoryId":214,"price":2290,"shortName":"Смартфон ARK Benefit S402 черный","categoryName":"Мобильные телефоны","brandName":"ARK"}\''
j = re.match('.*data-params=\'(.*)\'', s).group(1)
```

А затем преобразовать строку в словарь при помощи библиотеки [`ast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html)

```
import ast
d = ast.literal_eval(j)
```

или [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html):

```
import json
d = json.loads(j)
```

Comment: Спасибо, то, что надо!